# Check boxes are automatically set to the initial value even after giving the input. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, checkboxlist

I am building an app where users are supposed to be tagged in the question anyhow I managed to get the array or must say the list of the checked users but in UI the checkbox doesn't stay checked while the user has pressed the checkbox. It stays checked for a while then automatically goes unchecked. Which is the initial stage of the checkbox?

I have tried to build the list using gridview builder but that did not work because I am unable to get the list of checked users from that as I am not aware of it how to do that

Here is the code on which I am trying to work:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title ?? "Test"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getUsers(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            //print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  bool check = snapshot.data[index].istagged;
                  return CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name ?? "test"),
                    value: check,
                    subtitle:
                        Text(snapshot.data[index].autouid.toString() ?? "Test"),
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      setState(() => snapshot.data[index].istagged = value);
                      if (value == true) {
                        userid.add(snapshot.data[index].autouid);
                        check = value;
                      }
                      print(userid);
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want to have the list of userid checked and want the UI to be stay as the user select the checkbox. The checkbox should not be changed automatically. Any help in this really appreciated. Thank you